# Are there 3-colorable maps that can never be colored?

Tags: undecidability

I just watched this explanation of zero-knowledge proofs with Avi Wigderson: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ovdoxnfFV

Key claims from the video:

- Every formal statement can be translated into a map in a way that preserves truth. If a statement is true, its map will be 3-colorable. If not, it isn't 3-colorable https://youtu.be/5ovdoxnfFVc?t=1721

If every formal statement can be translated to a map, and suppose there's a true statement that can't be proven true by Gödel's incompleteness theorems, then doesn't that mean that no algorithm whether P, NP, or worse can exist to color it? Does that mean that there are some 3-colorable maps that can never be colored?

This seems wildly counterintuitive (which maybe is just the nature of Gödels' incompleteness theorems, which I haven't tried to understand the proof of). Or maybe I don't understand Gödel's incompleteness theorems (also likely). If I'm misunderstanding something though, it'd be helpful to know what to look into more.

Comment: What's a "map"? A $3$-coloration of any $3$-colorable (finite) graph is computable. Simply try all possible color assignments and check if one of them is valid.

Comment: @Steven based on this, I'd think that your statement about graphs would apply to map coloring https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_coloring#Mathematics "In mathematics there is a very strong link between map coloring and graph coloring, since every map showing different areas has a corresponding graph."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Every formal statement can be translated into a map in a way that preserves truth. If a statement is true, its map will be 3-colorable. If not, it isn't 3-colorable https://youtu.be/5ovdoxnfFVc?t=1721

Every formal statement **in propositional logic** can be translated to a map 3-coloring instance. The video is being very sloppy with calling this 'every mathematical statement', as there's many mathematical statements that aren't captured in propositional logic.

Propositional logic is decidable (it's equivalent to the SAT problem).

Comment: This is helpful. I have a background in number theory and I'm working through Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen and am still working on my understanding of complexity classes. Maybe that and reading fundamental papers like [Cook's](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/800157.805047) will get me there. Or will I need to dive into Discrete Mathematics?

Comment: @AustinKeller I can't really help because I don't know what your goal is.

Answer (score 1):

That's an informal description of what has been proven.  To make it precise, you need to understand what is meant by 'statement'.  Once you dive into it, you'll discover that 'statement' refers to one thing in the video and another thing in Godel's theorems.  So I recommend understanding the details of that claim and its proof.